# Array to object PHP Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, api, codeigniter

I have array looking like this

```
Array ( [0] => diamond.jpg [1] => default1.png [2] => White.png )
```

i make API, and my client want me to make the array become like this

```
data : [
{
"image_list": "diamond.jpg",
"image_list": " default1.png",
"image_list": " White.png",
 }
]
```

please help, sorry for my english

Comment: its showing null, you mean json_encode($array); ?

Comment: {"data":["diamond.jpg","default1.png","White.png"]} its show like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
        $images = ['diamond.jpg','default1.png', 'White.png'];
        print_r($images);
        $data = array();
        foreach($images as $key=>$value)
        {
            array_push($data,array("image_list"=>$value));
        }    
        echo json_encode($data);
?>
```